# Website which can handle database

Tags: javascript, php, drupal

I am a beginner here. I would like to create a website for our network , to collect some basic information & in making a graph out of it . The problem is that i don't know in which platform shall i proceed. I  am stuck with whether to use Drupal ( i have only heard of it & interested in studying ) or any other tools. Please help me to develop it efficiently.I know php & javascript basics. Give your opinion on it, please.

Comment: this is very vague... what kind of information? and what kind of graph?

Comment: information is like their work progress in the projects involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My honest opinion would be to try and dive into MySQLi and PHP and build a custom application. Mainly because it'll help you learn (trust me). It seems very hard at first but it'll be fun and you'll be able to achieve exactly what you want essentially.

As far as I know Drupal is a content management system, like a blog. So it's not really cut out for just gathering stats and making graphs from them. I suppose you could set up a basic Google Form for gathering information and then transferring it into a Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet. More work that way but it's very easy and no development work involved.

Really depends what type of information you're after to be honest. A quick Google search can return loads of cool web apps for small business teams etc if you have a look around and see what does what. Really some more information on what you're collecting would be best though.

Comment: I agree with Dan. dont try to tackle a CMS if you don't know the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has plugins for everything. Including one that hooks into google graphs.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/googlegraph/

It's also fairly cookie cutter and well documented. If you're not a programmer at heart, but more jus interested in using it as a quick and dirty tool to get a job done quick, it may be the app for you.

Comment: i dont know about wordpress, will it help me to use the database, also..?